# Mysterious hard disk space vanishing?

Tags: finder, disk-space

I'm running Snow Leopard on a Late 2009 unibody MacBook.

At the moment I was trying to do some late spring cleaning, and clearing up some HDD space. Now here's the weird part:

My User's folder shows that it occupies 179 GB of space. However when I go into the folder and add up the usage of all sub-folders and files within it, it comes to somewhere about 75GB.

I'm just very curious as to where the other 104 GB resides.

Any help would be appreciated! 
Thanks!

Comment: Could it be files in ~/.Trash/ or ~/Library/? How did you get the size of the home folder and the combined sizes? Do they match `du -sh ~`?

Comment: In addition to the good comment above to check actual disk usage, I would want to run disk utility and verify the catalog and other file system structures to be sure that isn't causing the discrepancy.

Comment: Could this be related to TimeMachine--local backups not transferred yet?

Comment: "ephsmith There is no local backups on 10.6. It was only introduced in 10.7

Comment: And ~/Library is visible in 10.6 as well.  But there are still invisible folders to take into account.

Comment: Thanks guys! It turns out that a folder called ".nx" (NX Client Folder) was hidden, and was eating up almost 80 GB of space). I used OmniDiskCleaner to find that out.

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest using one of the myriad apps available at your disposal to hunt down and find the rogue files that plague you? An excellent option that I found (and free to display the content, though not to delete from within the app) would be [the DaisyDisk app](http://www.daisydiskapp.com/). It'll show you exactly what's using up your space in a relatively intuitive/futuristic display.

From there, it's a little matter of simply deleting the files in question.